# AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

On the wikipedia page on 
["Nesbit's inequality"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality), the fifth proof ends as follows:

$$ \frac{x+z}{y}+\frac{y+z}{x}+\frac{x+y}{z}\geq 6$$
which is true, by AM-GM inequality.

I am wondering if the inequality is obvious / immediate from just looking at it and how you see this immediately without resorting to something like the following proof:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x+z}{y}+\frac{y+z}{x}+\frac{x+y}{z} &\geq 
2\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt{xz}}{y}+\frac{\sqrt{yz}}{x}+\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{z}\right) \\
&\geq 
6\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt{xz}}{y} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{yz}}{x} \cdot\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{z}\right)^{\frac13} \\
&=6\cdot(1)^{\frac13}=6
\end{align*}

Comment: Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524086/finding-minimum-fracxyz-fracxzy-fracyzx) what you have in mind?

Comment: You have $\frac{x}y$ plus it's reciprocal and three such sums. Each is at least $2$ by AM-GM.

Comment: @Lucian and Macavity: Yes, once you see that the expression can be expressed as three reciprocals, the inequality is immediate. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{x+z}{y}+\frac{y+z}{x}+\frac{x+y}{z}\geq 6$$ is equivalent to
$$ \frac{x^2 z+z^2x + y^2 z+z^2 y + x^2 y + y^2 x}{6}\geq xyz$$
which is true by the AM-GM inequality:
$$ \frac{x^2 z+z^2x + y^2 z+z^2 y + x^2 y + y^2 x}{6}\geq \sqrt[6]{x^6y^6z^6}.$$

Comment: yes, this is indeed a quick way to see it... as Lucian and Macavity mentioned in their comments another way to see it is if you see that the expression is three reciprocals.

Comment: What the downvote, 10 years after?

Answer (score 0):

$ \frac{x+y}{z} +\frac{y+z}{x} +\frac{z+x}{y} = \frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+y)z} +\frac{(y+z)^2}{(y+z)x} +\frac{(z+x)^2}{(z+x)y} \overset{Bergstrom}{\geqslant} \dfrac{(2(x+y+z))^2}{2(xy+yz+zx)} =  $

$= 2 \cdot \frac{(x+y+z)^2 }{xy+yz+zx}$

Since $(x+y+z)^2 
\geqslant 3(xy+yz+zx) $

then $ 2 \cdot \frac{(x+y+z)^2 }{xy+yz+zx} \geqslant 2\cdot 3$